# RServe - Scalability related

Tags: r, rjava, rserve

My requirement is to execute an R Script through a Java Webservice. The webservice needs a concurrency of 50.

We are using RServe to execute the R Script from the Java code. To achieve this, in the linux server , we created 50 instances of the RServe instances, started at different ports. Inside the java application, created a connection pool with 50 RConnection objects, each linked to one of the RServe instance created . For every execution, we fetch a RConnection from the pool, execute the R script, get the response value and then return the RConnection to the pool.

When we execute the webservice with a single user accessing, the R execution gets completed in 1 second. However , if I try to run the same webservice with a concurrency of 50, it takes around 30 seconds to execute the R Script inside the RServe. 
Since the actual R execution takes only 1 second if executed with single user, Im thinking that Im doing something wrong with the RServe. Any pointers would help.

Comment: Doesn't RServe fork as needed?  Just launch one and hit that with up to 50 requests...

Comment: The way I understood is that RServe will accept one incoming request at a time. Isnt this correct?  Even if I have 50 instances, why is the process going slow is what Im trying to understand

Comment: Only on Windows which I hope you do not use as your backend.

Comment: No, this is not on windows. So does it mean that I can create many instances of RConnection pointing to one RServe instance. Still, why would this solve my issue? Just curious, when I execute R through RServe, does it create new process which might be making it slower?

Comment: RServe can handle more than one connection at a time. In fact, it has been designed to deal with concurrency. I have been used it over some weeks and I haven't any problem using only one instance of RServe to handle all the connections. Have you tried to use only one RServe? Maybe the OS are overloaded, because each process needs it own memory space and resources.

I thins using one RServe it's a better approach, and let it to handle each connection using unix threads

Answer (score 0):

Although I think it is best to use one Rserve instance on Linux and let it just fork sub processes for parallel processing, it may not speed up processing at all.
From your question, it is not clear whether the application is used intensively and many concurrent requests are being processed continually. If that is the case, I assume that your R code is CPU intensive and the different processes just need to share CPU time, increasing the clock time needed to complete.

I tested just that kind of scenario and found these results with [top](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html)

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
33839 *****     20   0  269792  57104   3496 R  10.3  1.5   0:15.33 Rserve
33847 *****     20   0  269776  57100   3496 R  10.3  1.5   0:09.86 Rserve
33849 *****     20   0  269792  57104   3496 R  10.3  1.5   0:08.20 Rserve
33855 *****     20   0  269528  56840   3496 R  10.3  1.5   0:04.92 Rserve
29725 *****     20   0  268872  56836   4020 R  10.0  1.5   1360:13 Rserve
33841 *****     20   0  269784  57100   3496 R  10.0  1.5   0:14.42 Rserve
33843 *****     20   0  269796  57104   3496 R  10.0  1.5   0:12.50 Rserve
33844 *****     20   0  269792  57104   3496 R  10.0  1.5   0:11.72 Rserve
33852 *****     20   0  269512  56836   3496 R  10.0  1.5   0:06.38 Rserve
33856 *****     20   0  269520  56836   3496 R  10.0  1.5   0:04.05 Rserve
33842 *****     20   0  269776  57100   3496 R   9.3  1.5   0:13.20 Rserve
33851 *****     20   0  269784  57100   3496 R   9.3  1.5   0:06.69 Rserve
33857 *****     20   0  269512  56836   3496 R   9.3  1.5   0:03.15 Rserve
33834 *****     20   0  269792  57112   3496 R   9.0  1.5   0:18.56 Rserve
33835 *****     20   0  269784  57100   3496 R   9.0  1.5   0:17.33 Rserve
33837 *****     20   0  269776  57100   3496 R   9.0  1.5   0:16.46 Rserve
33846 *****     20   0  269784  57100   3496 R   9.0  1.5   0:10.17 Rserve
33848 *****     20   0  269796  57104   3496 R   9.0  1.5   0:08.61 Rserve
33853 *****     20   0  269532  56840   3496 R   9.0  1.5   0:05.34 Rserve
33858 *****     20   0  269532  56840   3496 R   9.0  1.5   0:02.27 Rserve
33838 *****     20   0  269796  57104   3496 R   8.6  1.5   0:15.74 Rserve
```

The %CPU sums up to 200%, corresponding to the two CPU cores available.

As you can see, the processes have the same priority (PR=20), and the shares of %CPU are almost equal, around 10%, so all of them will be allocated only 1/10th op the CPU time and will therefore take 10 times longer to complete, compared to the case of just one Rserve instance.

This is not 20 times longer, because a single Rserve process will only utilise one CPU core, leaving the other core 'sleeping'.

You simply need more CPU's if you want to speed up calculations. Also, if you don't want the 51st (or 101st, or 1001st) concurrent user to be denied access, it is better to implement a message queue. You can create multiple workers for the queue, which can distribute work-load over many CPU's, in different machines.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "As you can see, the processes have the same priority, and the shares of %CPU are almost equal. All of them will take 10 times longer to complete, compared to the case of just one Rserve instance. This is not 20 times, because a single Rserve process will only utilise one CPU core."

Comment: @ChintanShah, elaborated on the last paragraph.